# error Couldn't find "PLATFORM_NAME" variable in xcodebuild output

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, facebook

I'm trying to run my application on an iPhone simulator. from the console, I can see the build was successful. but on the next line, I get this.

> error Couldn't find "PLATFORM_NAME" variable in xcodebuild output. Please report this issue and run your project with Xcode instead. react-native.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite bizarre, but after getting this error I opened up the workspace in Xcode and ran it from there. Afterwards this error went away when running `react-native run-ios`

I suspect this might have something to do with the way Xcode 12 optimizes builds and that re-building it from Xcode somehow fixed it. I would like to know why, but I cbf'ed figuring it out myself.

Comment: drama, I have to every time build from Xcode and try again... HOURS WASTED with IOS

Comment: @KimSant React Native is a black hole for time. I haven't encountered this issue again since running XCode 13.1 - but it could be a fluke

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me because I clean up some image, and removed some native dependancies. All I did was `cd ios && pod install` then `yarn ios` to build again.

Answer (score 2):

Tried cleaning build folder and ran, it worked.

Xcode toolbar -> Product -> Clean build folder

Answer (score 2):

**Step - 1:** Clean the build folder from Xcode.

> Xcode toolbar -> Product -> Clean build folder

Step - 2: Delete the App installed in the device/simulator

Step - 3: Go to VSCode and move to **ios** directory using **command line** and just to be on the safer side, run the following command *(just to remove build folder via VSCode as well)*

> rm -rf build

**Step - 4:** Run

> pod install

Step - 5: Go back to the project folder and build the app again:

> npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

**Context:** `react-native upgrade` fails and cleaning the **build** folder doesn't work.

What works:

- Trash out the **node_modules** folder.
- Make `yarn install` to re-create dependencies.

It doesn't have any impact on "Podfile", but if you (future users) did, remove **Podfile.lock**, go to the **ios** folder and run `pod install` again. It must solve.

Answer (score -1):

This is obviously overkill, but a reboot fixed this problem for me. I turned off my computer and turned it on again, and it's now working well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

When I log in to "Podfile" I will not be able to say why it does not work, but if you (future users) do it, remove Podfile.lock, go to the ios folder and run it again pod install. It must be resolved